# Adding points to curve with bpy

Tags: python, data-blocks

I want to create a curve between two given points.
But I don't know how to add the points to the curve object.
When you create a new mesh data block, you have the from_pydata() function to add verts, but I can't find an equivalent for the cruve data block.
This is my code so far (just creating a new cruve data block and a curve object, then linking it to the collection)

```
def createCurve():
    star_point = [0,0,0]
    end_point = [1,0,0]
    curve = bpy.data.curves.new(name='curve_data',type='CURVE')
    curveObj = theObj = bpy.data.objects.new("curve_obj", curve)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(curveObj)
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to select the segment between the two points and then subdivide the segment with the the [subdivide operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.curve.html#bpy.ops.curve.subdivide)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I got it:

```
polyline = curve.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(1) 
polyline.points[0].co = start.to_4d()
polyline.points[1].co = end.to_4d()
```

I don't know why it has to be a vec4 (if you are using bezier splines it's vec3)
But it works now